# Scroll page up/down doesn't move cursor

Tags: visual-studio-code

At visual studio code, when I have a big file, I can scroll by Using Alt + PgUp / PgDn. However, the cursor doesn't follow this scroll and I don't know how to do it without using the mouse. Is there any way? Or I shouldn't be using Alt + PgUp / PgDn to accomplish that ?

Comment: Doesn't just PgUp/PgDn do what you want without the Alt?

Comment: Yup. Thanks! I should drink some coffee before posting